# Calculate Average Time Difference in Groups Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate the average time elapsed between actions for certain groups. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Name, Action_ID, Start_Time, End_Time
A, 11, 2019-05-01 09:10:00, 2019-05-01 09:20:00
A, 12, 2019-05-01 09:30:00, 2019-05-01 09:40:00
A, 13, 2019-05-01 09:50:00, 2019-05-01 10:00:00
B, 11, 2019-05-01 09:20:00, 2019-05-01 09:40:00
B, 12, 2019-05-01 09:45:00, 2019-05-01 09:55:00
```

I want to group by Name and get the average time elapsed between start time and end time of previous action. So basically to get something like this:

```
Name, Avg_Time_Elapsed
A, 10
B, 5
```

I created a new column called delta with the following code:

```
df['delta'] = df['Start_Time'] - df['End_Time'].shift(-1)
```

But it's giving me a strange result as its showing the difference is -1 days instead of mins/seconds. Any elegant way to write this code in python? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you do need a `groupby` here

```
df[['Start_Time','End_Time']]=df[['Start_Time','End_Time']].apply(pd.to_datetime,1)

df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : (x['Start_Time']-x['End_Time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().mean()/60)
Out[469]: 
Name
A    10.0
B     5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: i'm getting NaNs somehow. I think I need to get the difference first then do the groupby though right?

Comment: @ajax2000 I did not get that NaN , and I am using your sample data , please check with your data whether that is same with the sample data or not ..